# $X:= \left \{(0,0) \right\} ~~\bigcup ~\left \{(x,\sin \frac{1}{x}): x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right \}$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, real-numbers, connectedness, compactification

Consider the sets

> $X:= \left \{(0,0) \right\} ~~\bigcup ~\left \{(x,\sin \frac{1}{x}): x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right \}$

> $Y:= \left \{(0,0) \right\} ~~\bigcup ~\left \{(x,x\sin \frac{1}{x}): x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \right \}$

are metric spaces with metrics induced by the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. Let $B_{X}$ and
$B_{Y}$ be the open unit balls around (0,0) in $X$ and $Y,$ respectively.
Then which of the following statements are true ?

1. The closure of $B_{X}$ in $X$ is compact.
2. The closure of $B_{Y}$ in $Y$ is compact.

$B_Y$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R^2}$, hence it is compact.
$B_X$ is bounded. Is it closed ?

Its limit points are $\{ (0,y)| y\in [-1,1]\}$

How to conclude is it a closed set or not ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the x term in the y-coordinate

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $Y$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$. Indeed, let $(a_n,a_n\sin\frac{1}{a_n})_{n \in \mathbb N}  $ be a convergent sequence of $Y$, with $$(a_n,a_n\sin\frac{1}{a_n}) \to (y_1,y_2).$$
It's not hard to see that $(y_1,y_2) \in Y$. (In the problematic case of  $y_1 = 0$, we have that  $y_2 = \lim_n a_n \sin \frac {1} {a_n}=0$ and so $(y_1,y_2) \in Y$).
Therefore, $ \overline {B_Y}=Y \cap \overline {B_{\mathbb R} } $ is compact.

On the other hand, $ \overline {B_X}$ is not closed (and therefore not compact). Take for example the  sequence $$
\Big (\frac {1/2}{2n\pi + \pi } ,  \sin (2n\pi +\pi/2) /2 \Big )_n \subset \overline {B_X}$$
Then,

$$\Big (\frac {1}{2n\pi + \pi/2 } , \sin (2n\pi +\pi/2) \Big )_n = \Big ( \frac {1}{2n\pi + \pi/2 },  1 \Big )_n \to (0,1) \notin X .$$

Comment: $(\frac {1}{2n\pi + \pi/2 } , \sin (2n\pi +\pi/2))\not\in B_X$

Comment: Yeah, just multiply it with an appropriate coefficient.

Comment: if $(x,\sin\frac{1}{x})\in B_X$ then $(\lambda \cdot x, \lambda\cdot sin\frac{1}{x})$ isn't necessary in $X$.  You should be careful with that

Comment: True, but the sequence is bounded and so it belongs to a ball of radius r, and so the proof is still correct.

Comment: You took convergent sequence $(a_n,\sin\frac{1}{a_n})_{n \in \mathbb N}  $ in $Y$, I think it should be  $(a_n,a_n\sin\frac{1}{a_n})_{n \in \mathbb N}  $

Comment: Yes, you are right.