# Challenging problem for me in General topology

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $X=\{(0,0)\}\cup \{(x,sin\frac{1}{x}:x\in\Bbb{R}- \{0\}\}$ and $Y=\{(0,0)\}\cup \{(x,xsin\frac{1}{x}:x\in\Bbb{R}- \{0\}\}$ are metric spaces with metrics induced by the Euclidean metric of $\Bbb{R}^2$. Let $B_X$ and $B_Y$ be the open unit balls around $(0,0)$ in $X$ and $Y$ , respectively.

Prove or disprove:

- The closure of $B_X$ in $X$ is compact.
- The closure of $B_Y$ in $Y$ is compact.

Let $(t_n,t_nsin\frac{1}{t_n})$ be the convergent sequence in $Y$. and $(t_n,t_nsin\frac{1}{t_n})\to (p,q)$. We can choose $p=0,q=0$. therefore $(p,q)\in Y$. How to show that $Y$ is closed? It seems 'yes it is'. But I am uncomfortable at writing it formally.

I have no idea about first.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3786276/x-left-0-0-right-bigcup-left-x-sin-frac1x-x-in-math/3786327#3786327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence $\{X_n\}$ with

$$X_n= \left(\frac{1}{2 n \pi + \frac{\pi}{4}},\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)$$ is a sequence of $B_X \cap X$ for $n$ large enough. However$\{X_n\}$ has no converging subsequence in the closure of $B_X$ in $X$. Hence the closure of $B_X$ in $X$ is not compact.

Regarding $Y$, the map defined on $\mathbb R$

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
(x, x\sin \frac{1}{x}) & x \neq 0\\
(0,0) & x = 0
\end{cases}$$
is continuous. Therefore, the image of $[-2,2]$ under $f$ is compact as $[-2,2]$ is a compact interval. As the closure of $B_Y$ in $Y$ is a closed subset of $f([-2,2])$, it is compact.

Comment: What about $B_Y$? please see my complete question.

Comment: Also what is the intuition behind taking such sequence $\{X_n\}$.

Comment: Answer updated regarding $B_Y$. Intuition regarding $B_X$ is to look at the geometry and to find a sequence with no convergent sub sequence.